# A dynamic method name (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic, selector

I have several methods, like below:

```
- (void)methodA;
- (void)methodB;
- (void)methodC;
```

and they are used depending on some conditions.

Now I want to dynamically use them, and I tried this:

```
NSString *methodName;
if(_flag == A) methodName = @"methodA";
else if (_flag == b) methodName = @"methodB";
else methodName = @"methodC";

[self performSelector:@selector(methodName)];
```

but it seems wrong.

So how should I use a dynamic method name for a given receiver depending on different situations?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
[self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(methodName)]
```

Comment: Thansk a lot! That's what I want.

Answer (score 2):

why don't you do in this manner??

```
if(_flag == A)
     [self performSelector:@selector(methodA)];
else if (_flag == b) 
     [self performSelector:@selector(methodB)];
else 
     [self performSelector:@selector(methodC)];
```

As the `@selector` needs function to call and not `NSString`.

Comment: Thanks for caring! Cuz I'm integrating my codes, so the real situation is much more complicated, I'm trying my best to reduce if else sentences. But thank you for your help!